# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqi_query()

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data from text box to a database but it's giving me this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqi_query() in C:\wamp\www\SqlInputForm.php on line 16)

on this line

```
{
    if($username==true)
    {
        $insert = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO reuel VALUES ('','$fullname','$username','$password')");
        echo " inserted";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "failed";
    }
}
```

Comment: See my answer, just change the query according to it, replace the table name in my code.

Comment: `mysqli =/= mysqi` (you're missing an `L`).

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO 
reuel (column1,column2,column3) 
VALUES 
('$fullname','$username','$password')");
```

Write it like this, only change column1,2,3 to the real name of the column it should be inserted to. $connection must be changed to whatever variable represents your mysqli connect

Comment: Don't you have a connection established to your DB?

Comment: Then you only have to change $connection to whatever you have named your variable in front of new mysqli("...") or mysqli_connect("..."). Often used in tutorials is $sql or $con or $connection. Of course your db.php needs to be included in your file you are executing queries in

Comment: do i put @db coz thats wat i put in front of mysqli .. ($db = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database))

Comment: Yes, replace $connection with $db in the query. Please mark the answer as correct.